# Casper JS Login on Encrypted Session

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I'm trying to log-in to 
http://insider.espn.go.com/insider/pickcenter/

The input type on clicking sign-in don't have any identifiers. Can somebody please help on how to do it?